# How do I stop my clipless shoes and pedals from squeaking?

Tags: clipless, noise

I'm riding with [Shimano SD66 sandals](http://www.shimano.com.au/publish/content/global_cycle/en/au/index/products/shoes/mtb/product.-code-SH-SD66.html). They are awesome sandals and it's so comfortable riding without worrying about socks and shoes. I'm using Shimano pedals.

I'm getting a squeaking sound, mainly from one shoe/pedal at the top of the power stroke. I'm almost certain it's from the shoe/pedal because just adjusting the angle of my foot a little (inside the play allowed by the cleat/pedal) makes the noise stop.

I'm assuming that the shoe and pedal are deforming/conforming to each other and have started to rub at the most common positioning.

I'd normally look at lubricating, but don't want to use grease as that will track through my house and office.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: FWIW I've tried chain lube, heaver bike-fittings lube, silicon lube, and most of them only last a day or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than use grease, you can try using a 'dry' or wax based chain lube.

1. Apply the lube to the flat clips on each pedal - hit both sides if they are double sided mtb pedals.
2. If you think the squeak may be coming from the pedal itself, rather than the friction between the pedal and the clip, apply some lube to the spindle attachment points where the pedal rotates around the shaft.
3. Wipe away any excess.
4. Hold onto a wall or go for a ride and and clip in and out of the bicycle pedals until the lube is adequately distributed and worked in.
5. Repeat all steps if still squeaking.

If you carefully wipe off the excess from your shoes/cleats and the pedals, you won't be tracking anything around your house after your ride.

If after a second application the squeak remains it may be a problem with the bearings in the pedals - some can be overhauled, but others it makes more sense just to replace.

Comment: Or just cleat-in through a sheet of waxed paper.

Comment: @daniel-r-hicks I've never tried that.  I will have to give it a shot.

Comment: I gave that a shot today and it worked perfectly. There was also a very noticeable increase in the float on the pedal. I like it! How often do you find you need to re-lube? Also I've seen people recommending Armour-All. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Mac I hate to say it, but 'as needed'.  I do it either when the squeak comes back, or if I think about I hit them with a few drops when I lube my chain.

Answer (score 1):

I have rubbed a block of wax on the pedal/cleat interface to deal with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same clicking problem. Found it to be the pedal bearing arrangement. The pedal relys on the mating of the tension bolt against the bearing (which is located on the outer side). Poor design. Once the bearing and pedal body begin to shift the mating surface starts to click. Solution...Loctite the bearing to the pedal body and file down the pedal body where the tightening bolt seats to allow for more tension on the mating surface.

Answer (score -2):

This is a common problem with SPD cleats. You may want to check the cleats for wear and mount them in the middle of the slots on the bottom of the shoes pointing exactly forward. Make sure the bolts are tight and give them another go. If the squeak has gone then try edging the cleats forwards/back to where you had them.

*But why bother wasting time...*

The other option is to get the Time ATAC pedal system. These are a much better pedal system because of how the cleat gets held and how the 'float' works. The pedals are also a bit more considerate if you catch your shins with them. The ch-mo ones are practically indestructible. An investment in them will be an expense you probably don't need right now but ten years down the line they will be amongst your most prized possessions and so pleased to have had ten years of use out of them. Google 'atac vs spd' and you will find that the only people that beg to differ are those that never tried Time. If there is a 'problem' with your pedal stroke then the ATAC cleats/pedals will be a lot more forgiving and easier on the knees.

Comment: Hehe. Do you have shares in Time?

Comment: @Mac I have always recommended Shimano over Time in retail situations but always used Time myself. The situation is akin to my computing choice - advising people to get the latest Microsoft but using Linux myself. In this analogy I guess that 'Crank Bros' are OSX. Anyway, SPD pedals are bad for beginners and I have karma problems for having pushed so many people to get them without offering them the choice of something better.